# ng-repeat fails inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a simple app that's using ng-view, with ng-repeat inside it. At first I was doing it without ng-view, and it worked fine. Then I converted to ng-view, and the ng-repeat failed. Everything else worked, just the ng-repeat spat out the $var and not the actual values. (Stranger still, if I clicked on the "menu" link, it would produce another chunk of spat-out $var instead of changing pages.)

The answers here indicated I need to put the items on $rootscope, except I can't seem to get it work no matter which way I try it. The entire thing just fails silently, so I don't even have error messages to go on. From what I can figure out, this means $rootscope is being read, but something else is failing. I have no idea what.

I set up a plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/fuz6JELf1em7VHrY41u4 with the second-to-last attempt. My current attempt tries a different variation, using a service instead, but this doesn't work, either.

```
app.controller('VerbsController', [ '$rootScope', function( $rootScope ) {
    $rootscope.jverbs = [
        {id: 41, name:"Furu", vClass:"Class I", plainPreAffR :"furu", plainPreAffK:"ふる", vKanji1:"下る, 降る", vDef1:"to fall, descend", vType1:"v.i. ", vKanji2:"振る", vDef2:"to wave, shake, swing; throw (dice); reject, abandon", vType2:"v.t."  },
        {id: 42, name:"Futoru", vClass:"Class I", plainPreAffR :"futoru", plainPreAffK:"ふとる", vKanji1:"太る", vDef1:"to gain weight, become fat", vType1:"v.i."  },
        {id: 43, name:"Fuyasu", vClass:"Class I", plainPreAffR :"fuyasu", plainPreAffK:"ふやす",vKanji1:"増やす", vDef1:"to increase, augment", vType1:"v.t."  }
    ];
}]);

app.controller('MenuController', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.olist = function() { $location.path('/list'); };
});

app.controller('ListController', function( $rootscope, $scope, $location) {
    $scope.omenu = function() { $location.path('/menu'); };
});
```

It's got to be something annoyingly small that I'm just missing. If anyone can help me find it, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked you plunkr and tried to fix the issue. There were many issue with you plunkr code, mostly related to incorrect case used and the route path were pointing to `partial` folder which is non existent.

But it believe the main issue was that your ListController definition was incorrect which was causing the template rendering to fail.

This is how it looked earlier (there is even a type with `$rootScope`)

```
app.controller('ListController', function( $rootscope, $scope, $location) {
    $scope.omenu = function() { $location.path('/menu'); };
});
```

This is the correct way

```
app.controller('ListController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location',function( $rootScope, $scope, $location) {
    $scope.omenu = function() { $location.path('/menu'); };
}]);
```

You see it in action here

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4O5bgy6NH4MIH8A0xWI?p=preview

Comment: Oh, the dangers of cut-and-paste late at night! Thank you so much for the corrections. One question: by incorrect case you mean capitalization patterns, or something else?

Comment: Yes capitalization issue was one (especially $rootScope). Plunkr path in routeproviders were refering to partial folder.  I did not understand you there is a seperate page for menu. The menu should be included in the main page using `ng-include'

Comment: Gotcha. Still getting the hang of this, so every tip helps. Thanks!